# Why don't WordPress post slugs allow accents?

Tags: permalinks, slug

If you create a post whose title has an accent in it and some other unicode character in it, eg `à 漢語 title thing`, its slug (permalink) will become `a-漢語-title-thing`... ie, the `à` was converted into a regular `a`, but those unicode Chinese characters were left intact.
Why doesn't WordPress leave the accented characters alone?
I created a code snippet to tell WordPress to leave them alone

```
function mn_sanitize_title($modified_title, $original_title, $context)
{
    // the $modified_title may have had accents removed, but not the $original_title
    return $original_title;
}
// set this filter to run BEFORE WP already ran the title through `sanitize_title_with_dashes`
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'mn_sanitize_title', 5, 3);
```

and it seems to work fine (accented characters are left intact in post slugs) so I'm wondering why WordPress developers removed accented characters from post slugs in the first place?

Comment: I would note that you may have removed some security features in the process, `<script>` may now be a valid post slug. I would also note that none of the non-ascii characters are valid as URLs without specialised encoding

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Tom! But one really important note: my code snippet runs BEFORE WP runs the slug through `sanitize_title_with_dashes`. So it's not totally circumventing all of the post slug sanitization- just the part that removes the accented characters. The slug still gets run through all of `sanitize_title_with_dashes`. So it removes scripts, and  encodes the non-ascii characters. I've tested it and found that's what it does...
So I suppose I should clarify my question- why are accented characters not just percent-encoded like all other non-ascii characters?

Comment: "why something is like that" is a very poor type of question. Unless there is a good documentation (in which case you would have probably found it yourself) or you know the person that wrote the code, it is basically impossible to do more than guessing.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun for the feedback. Where would you suggest discussing this? Or how should I have phrased the question? 
I suppose I was hoping someone out there knew the person who wrote the code, or was more familiar with the history of WordPress' code, would have some helpful info. But yes, having an exact answer, like "because otherwise, X would have happened" might be difficult.

Comment: you can ask on the wordpress slack, but  I will be very surprised if anyone will know without digging in the history of trac tickets and maybe even then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`sanitize_title()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/be6aa715fedb64fba8a848706e050f489c56df82/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2152) function uses [`remove_accents()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/be6aa715fedb64fba8a848706e050f489c56df82/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1594) right away. Both of these functions date way back to <= v1.2.1. The `remove_accents()` function is a hard coded list of accent characters to explicitly replace a handful of characters in a few specific languages. The inline comment and [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents) simply say:

> Converts all accent characters to ASCII characters.

[According to RFC 3986, valid URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) are only ASCII.

So (although I can't find any evidence of this) I assume what's going on here is that the accent characters are replaced to make a ascii-valid URL for languages that have just a *few* almost-ascii characters. And that this originates from way back.

Invalid URL `/à-b-c/` becomes valid `/a-b-c/` (instead of valid encoded `/%wtv-b-c/` title).

---

As to why the Chinese characters (which aren't ASCII) are not replaced, striped out, or encoded/escaped by WordPress seems to be intentional. Again, I can't find any documentation on this, but the characters aren't even close to ascii-valid like aforementioned accent characters are, so there's nothing to replace them with. Escaping the URL would be ridiculous, nearly unusable. And [this entire thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547940), and notably [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667242/9576899), shed some light on these characters in URLs:

> [addresses with non-ASCII characters] are not URIs (and therefore not URLs, since URLs [are a type of URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.3)). If we consider ourselves beholden to the terminology of existing IETF standards, then we should properly call them IRIs (Internationalized Resource Identifiers), as defined in [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987), which are technically not URIs but can be converted to URIs simply by percent-encoding all non-ASCII characters in the IRI.

So I would assume with WordPress not having handlers for these characters, it's leaving it up to the user and the browser in these cases, but it's been cleaning up accents since the early days.

*(I realize this answer doesn't satisfy the question, but hopefully it provides a bit more info to get you closer to your answer).*

Comment: not to dispute the answer, but I want to point out that 1.2 was ages ago and the modern day browsers might support non ascii characters much better than they have done back then, and therefor whatever was the reason might not apply any more.

Comment: maybe I should be more specific. While URLs are ASCII, everything which is not can be decoded into ASCII and will be displayed "as intended" in the browser.

Comment: @MarkKaplun the RFC dictates that non-ascii characters aren't supported, hence URL encoding. We get this every few months when a developer is working with Arabic or Kanji and sees encoded values in URLs and gets confused why WP isn't outputting proper characters as entered in slugs

Comment: @TomJNowell that is not a "reason". Maybe a reason is that browsers do not support the full unicode character set properly in the address bar, but one may claim that this should be left to the user to decide if he is willing to live with it as it might have impact on software that does better content parsing like google (not arguing that filtering is wrong, just saying that it is hard to know the original reason, for example at that time hebrew support was horrible and my clients preferred to avoid using "pretty urls") .

Comment: They do, hence how encoded values are displayed as arabic or chinese characters in the address bar. URLs simply don't do unicode characters because that's the standard that was agreed upon. If you send a HTTP request with unicode characters it will get punted or converted to fit the RFC. There's literally an ISO standard that forbids it, and another ISO standard on how to fit non-ASCII characters in URLs

Comment: See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: and for domains themselves https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode via IDNA encoding. It's a standards/RFC thing

Comment: thanks @DavidSword, ya I think that solves the mystery. So basically, replacing accented characters with non-accented characters is old, probably before browsers started automatically converting ugly percent-encoded characters into pretty unicode characters. Also, the non-accented characters are pretty good equivalent to the accented ones.
But for other unicode characters, there is no good equivalent, so percent-encoding is the only option.

Comment: @TomJNowell I think you are confusing how things are being displayed and how they are sent. Browsers encode properly the url, and at least in hebrew this preserves accents, can even edit accent in the address bar. At least google search have no problem with handling hebrew accents and when you search for a word with an accent you also see the parameters being accented in the adressbar

Answer (score 4):

Since we already have one "answer" I will add an "answer" of my own, although it is no more than a guess as well.

The important aspect is the state of i18n 10+ years ago, and this applies not only to the web related software but also to the OSs themselves. Back then IDN was not yet a standard and the web was ASCII oriented, and it would not have done the web much good to be better at i18n because almost no major OS supported it out of the box, and if for example you wanted windows that support hebrew you had to buy a special version, or install a language pack. But even if you had all the appropriate language packs installed, browers had bug and in the era before chrome it would have taken years before browsers had new versions, and web servers also had bugs in properly processing URL and properly pass them to the PHP layer.

The solution for latin scripts was easy, just convert anything which is not ascii to phonetically correct ASCII equivalence. It is very telling that the code do not handle hebrew although it has similar accent problems. My guess about hebrew is that both accents are less important in the normally read text (kids learning at young age to "imagine" accents based on understand the word in its context, and the places where you actually need them is when a text in foreign language is using the hebrew script for example [yiddish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish)), and that by the time the web got really going in israel those bugs were mostly fixed (although there was some period of time in which people preferred to avoid the problem by not using pretty permalinks which became default only in 4.4, or use slugs in english).

Now day I do not think that function serves anything and like other parts of wordpress code it is maintained as part of inertia and not based on actual need.